# Efficient way of copying data from one azure SQL DB to another

Tags: azure-sql-database

Trying to optimize a copy of table's content between two azure sql databases.

Currently, one DB has an external table setup:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[Database2_TableA] (
    [Col1] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ColN] [varchar](200) NULL
)
    WITH (
    DATA_SOURCE = [Database2],
    SCHEMA_NAME = N'dbo',
    OBJECT_NAME = N'TableA'
    );
```

Then, inside a stored proc, this statement copies the data

```
insert into TableA1 select * from Database2_TableA
```

The table is large (lots of large columns and rows), and the copy takes too long.

Is there more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Do you think about using SSMS import and export data for the large table data copy?

Comment: Hi Greg Balajewicz, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer or vote up it . This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table has large data, I think you can think about using bellow ways:

1. SSMS Import and Export Data. it support copy data between two Azure SQL databases.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Using the SSMS `Generate Scripts` to get the data:
- Launch SQL Server Management Studio and login to your database
- Right click on your database name and click on Generate Scripts
- Select Choose Objects on the left hand side menu
- Click on Select Specific database objects on the right part of the
  window
- Checkmark the tables you wish to copy
- Click on Set Scripting Options on the left
- Select Save scripts to a specific location and Save to new query
  window
- Click on the Advanced button as shown below:
  [image]

When you click on Advanced you will get a list of options, go down to the bottom of the list and select either Data, Schema and Data or Schema only for Types of data to script:
[image]

Reference: [Copy Data Between Two Azure Databases](https://accessexperts.com/blog/2014/06/25/copying-data-two-azure-databases/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was the only efficient method